# Numpy matrix multiplication with it's inv

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, floating-point

Please pardon me if it is  a dumb question.
I was just exploring numpy in python shell and I ran these lines

```
>>> from numpy.linalg import inv
>>> from numpy import dot, transpose
>>> a = np.matrix('1,2;3,4')
>>> print a
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
>>> print inv(a)
[[-2.   1. ]
 [ 1.5 -0.5]]
>>> print a.dot(inv(a))
[[1.0000000e+00 0.0000000e+00]
 [8.8817842e-16 1.0000000e+00]]
```

In the last line I was expecting value

```
[[1,0]
 [0,1]]
```

(identity matrix), however I got some non-zero value at (1,0) pos.

Comment: You can't expect exact results when working with floating point numbers. Maybe some kind of norm `||a - I||²` will work. The first answer to the question posted by @GarbageCollector explains it pretty well.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `print` in python console.

Comment: All that being said, `numpy` *could* have been simplifying the expression and just returning an identity matrix of same rank. It would also speed things up for large matrices.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: For this, you'd need to work with `sympy`, not `numpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of floating point arithmetic, and all the shortcomings associated with it. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for a detailed understanding of why this happens.

Your result is not perfect, but it is *close enough*, and that is the key. `inv` of course, does not compute the *exact* result (it uses numerical methods after all). Correspondingly, A * A_inv isn't going to be exactly the identity matrix, but it will be close enough. You can test *closeness* using `np.allclose`.

```
np.allclose(a * inv(a), np.eye(2))
True
```

(Note that `a * b` computes the dot product for `matrix` objects.)